# Null Object Reference on Retrieving Nested XML Elements with Linq / C#

Tags: c#, linq

this is the XML I am parsing:

```
<FEED>
<FEED_HEADER>
    <FEED_NAME>foo</FEED_NAME>
    <FEED_CODE>foobar123</FEED_CODE>
</FEED_HEADER>
<FEED_CONTENT>
    <DOC>
        <PUB_DATE>2011-12-01</PUB_DATE>
        <TITLE>Monkey Bombs</TITLE>
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <PUB_DATE>2011-12-10</PUB_DATE>
        <TITLE>A Silly Hat</TITLE>
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <PUB_DATE>2011-12-25</PUB_DATE>
        <TITLE>Wind Blows Up My Skirt</TITLE>
    </DOC>
</FEED_CONTENT>
</FEED>
```

And I am parsing it with this linq code I have written to build a list of objects based on the DOC element and its subsequent elements:

```
public List<Review> GetReviews(string filePath, FileInfo file, DirectoryInfo directory, XElement xmlDoc)
    {
        IEnumerable<BookReview> reviews = null;
        try
        {
            reviews = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("DOC")
                      select new BookReview()
                      {
                          PubDate = item.Element("PUB_DATE").Value,
                          Title = item.Element("TITLE").Value,
                      };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Info(string.Format("Error while parsing file {0}\n", file.Name) + " " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return reviews.Cast<Review>().ToList();
    }
```

In the past, this code would work where the DOC element was just beneath the root element, now that the DOC element is further nested into the FEED_CONTENT element, I am getting a null reference exception. I thought LINQ could directly access what I want without knowing where it is in the hierarchy. **So what do I need to write to access the DOC elements now?**

Comment: this should work. Your XML as pasted though is either incomplete or invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query should work fine, given your current XML example. I suspect your real XML document has a missing `PUB_DATE` or `TITLE` element, which would cause the `NullReferenceException` to be thrown.

In such cases you can cast the element to a string instead of trying to access the `Value` property. If the element doesn't exist, it will return a null result which you will need to handle properly by writing additional logic later in your process.

```
PubDate = (string)item.Element("PUB_DATE"),
Title = (string)item.Element("TITLE")
```

Comment: So you are saying there may be a missing value for either of the two elements or a missing element? This may be the case as the real XML is very large with hundreds of DOC elements.

Comment: @fullNelson a missing element, not an empty element. An empty element (or missing value) will be treated as `String.Empty`.

Comment: +1 for not using `Value`. The typecasting is much safer and nicer. It handles most types such as `int`, `bool` etc. This is a major+ of Linq-Xml.

Comment: Wow. So out of the thousands and thousands of DOC elements (which represent individual "reviews", there was indeed a couple of busted elements. Bravo, Ahmad. Kind of hard to see that with such a large document. Thanks to all that have helped, you were all spot on, but there was a bigger problem with the XML. Shame you cant put a watch on the elements to see which one is broken...

Comment: @MiG Yeah, this is the only thing that was able to expose a deeper problem with the XML that my code wasn't revealing. It wasn't about using Decendents(), it was a messed up piece of XML.

Comment: @AhmadMageed Actually, this does bring up one more question: Since I dont know which element(out of the thousands that there are), do I need to re-iterate through the collection I am returning to check for nulls?

Comment: @fullNelson yes, this is what I meant by needing to handle it properly later in your process. The missing elements will be null, so do you want to assign a default value? Filter them out? To filter them out you could add a `Where` statement that keeps the elements where neither of those properties are null. You could assign an empty string or another default string, instead of null, using the null coalescing operator: `Title = (string)item.Element("TITLE") ?? String.Empty`. The good thing about this is you can do so as part of your original query instead of performing an extra iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code -- the one problem I ran into was that your  element needed to be closed.  After I modified the XML that way, I was able to acccess the DOC elements fine.  Here's the code I ran:

```
        public class Review { }
        public class BookReview : Review
        {
            public string PubDate;
            public string Title;

        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            string xml = @"
<FEED>
<FEED_HEADER>
    <FEED_NAME>foo</FEED_NAME>
    <FEED_CODE>foobar123</FEED_CODE>
</FEED_HEADER>
<FEED_CONTENT>
    <DOC>
        <PUB_DATE>2011-12-01</PUB_DATE>
        <TITLE>Monkey Bombs</TITLE>
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <PUB_DATE>2011-12-10</PUB_DATE>
        <TITLE>A Silly Hat</TITLE>
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <PUB_DATE>2011-12-25</PUB_DATE>
        <TITLE>Wind Blows Up My Skirt</TITLE>
    </DOC>
</FEED_CONTENT>
</FEED>";   // NOTE: I closed  the <FEED> element!
            var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            IEnumerable<BookReview> reviews = null;
            try
            {
                reviews = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("DOC")
                          select new BookReview()
                          {
                              PubDate = item.Element("PUB_DATE").Value,
                              Title = item.Element("TITLE").Value,
                          };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //...
            }

            foreach (var review in reviews)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", review.PubDate, review.Title);
            } 
            var reviews2 = reviews.Cast<Review>().ToList();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And the output:

```
2011-12-01, Monkey Bombs
2011-12-10, A Silly Hat
2011-12-25, Wind Blows Up My Skirt
```

Comment: Thanks, JohnD, with this simplified XML, it would run correctly, there must be something else about the xml that I am not representing here correctly in order for anyone to get a clear idea of what may be wrong. Again, I had to use a watered-down example of the levels of XML I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

You dot your way into the FEED_CONTENT in from of your query. That is something like

```
reviews = from item in xmlDoc.Element("FEED_CONTENT").Descendants("DOC")
    select new BookReview()
    {
        PubDate = item.Element("PUB_DATE").Value,
        Title = item.Element("TITLE").Value
    }
};
```

Comment: I did "walk" my way down just as you had suggested before posting this question, and it didn't seem to work at all. I am not wondering if its something else about the access to the other parts of the XML. Unfortunately, the XML is too complex to post here in full.